# Another issue with namespaces in xml with xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces

and it's valid with schema. But I have problem with getting to in with xpath in python.

```
<spring:beans xmlns="http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
  http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/ http://membrane-soa.org/schemas/proxies-1.xsd">

  <fileExchangeStore
    id="myFileExchangeStore"
    dir="./exchanges"
    maxDays="30" />
```

I wrote this part of script:

```
from lxml import etree

a = etree.parse("output.xml")

r=a.xpath('//empty:beans',
          namespaces= { 'empty':"http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/",
                        'spring':"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans",
                        "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                        'schemaLocation':"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/ http://membrane-soa.org/schemas/proxies-1.xsd"})
```

Now I'm stuck with this xpath. In this case "r" is empty list. I've tried several solutions from stackoverflow, how to handle namespaces in xpath, but without success. I'll be thankful for any suggestion how to get content of "fileExchangeSotre".

Comment: `fileExchangeStore` has no content. Do you mean you want to get values of attributes `id`, `dir`, `maxdays`?

Comment: yes, this is only a part of my xml. Even that fileExchangeStore doesn't have text attribute, but it has tag attribute, and I can't access to it

Comment: `//fileExchangeStore/@*` match any attribute, `//fileExchangeStore/*`- any child node, `//fileExchangeStore//*`- any descendant node, `//fileExchangeStore/text()` - text node. Or you mean you want to get as output node name - `fileExchangeStore`?

Comment: `print(a.xpath('//fileExchangeStore/*'))` return empty list, and 

`print(a.xpath('//fileExchangeStore/*')[0])
      IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: If element looks like this `<fileExchangeStore/>`, `'//fileExchangeStore/*'` will return empty list as it has no child nodes. Can you share exact output you want to get?

Comment: It would be nice to have at least option to edit i.e. "id" or "maxDays" tag in fileExchangeStore with xpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138626/discussion-between-andersson-and-darvark).

Comment: @darvark `fileExchangeStore` inherits default namespce, which, in your code has been mapped to the prefix `empty` : `//empty:fileExchangeStore/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
namespaces= { 'empty':"http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/",
                    'spring':"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans",
                    "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                    'schemaLocation':"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/ http://membrane-soa.org/schemas/proxies-1.xsd"}

r = a.xpath('/spring:beans/*[local-name()="fileExchange"]/@*', namespaces=namespaces)
```